# php get result of file_get_contents as array

Tags: php

i'm trying to receive a response from an url as :

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/test');
```

it simply returns some informations separated by `|`
example :

```
info1|info2|info3
```

i want to get that result as an array

something like $result = `array(file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/test'));`

I just got involved in php stuffs excuse me for any confusing terms !

Comment: google `php explode`

Comment: Take that string and use `explode()` to turn it into an array. Here is a link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just got it !

```
explode("|",$result);
```

Comment: Next time, search before you post.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple to do:

```
$resultArray = explode("|", $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()` to separate the data by pipe.

```
$result = explode('|',file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/test'))
```